# orthogonal vectors of vector $(a,b)$ which is of same length as that of vector $(a,b)$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

We have a vector $(a',b')$ which is orthogonal to vector $(a,b)$ and has same length as that of vector $(a,b)$ and lies counterclockwise of vector $(a,b)$.If vector $(a,b)$ is represented by $1i+ 1j$ .Then what should be vector $(a',b')$? How do we solve for vector $(a',b')$?

Comment: Just draw the vector on a paper, turn the paper 90 degrees counterclockwise, and see what you get...

Comment: @HansLundmark  can you just answer it please ?

Comment: Did you even try what I suggested? It's so easy that a child could do it.

Comment: If you recall the definition of orthogonal and you know it has the same length and is rotated the answer should be extremely obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be what you looking for, but here's an alternative approach exploiting the ease of rotating in the complex plane.

Identify $(a,b)$ with the complex number $z=a+bi$. The vector orthogonal to $(a,b)$ in counterclockwise direction, is the vector you get by rotating over 90° in the same direction. In the complex plane, this rotation corresponds to the simple multiplication with $i$, so the corresponding complex number is:
$$z' = iz = i(a+bi) = bi^2+ia = -b+ai$$
and this corresponds to the vector $(a',b') = (-b,a)$.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

M and M' is orthogonal since the angle between two vectors is 90 degrees. Just rotate your point 90 degrees in clockwise direction